# How to make the wordpress editor readonly?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-editor

How to make the wordpress editor readonly like readonly inputs.
i am using following code for to display the editor in the page

```
<?php
$args= array( 
'quicktags' => false,
'media_buttons' => false
);
wp_editor( wpautop(stripslashes($my_text)), "my_text", $args);
?>
```

any option available in its settings or any other method?

Comment: <textarea readony></textarea> ??? if yes, just read the manual to see how to send attributes.

Comment: pass `readonly => true`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tiny_mce_before_init` to modify the tiny mce arguments to set it as readonly

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', function( $args ) {

    if ( 1 == 1 )
         $args['readonly'] = 1;

    return $args;
} );
```

Comment: may I ask why is the `1 == 1` if-condition necessary?

Comment: @OrelBiton It's not. My guess is that the answerer wanted to show how you can use a conditional block to specify when a readonly content editor would be necessary. It's up to you to decide what those conditions actually are.

Comment: I realise this is an old question but I have the same requirement and this answer is not working for me. I do not know if the timyMCE code has changed but the readonly attribute is not getting added to the textarea. I can see in the page source that it is getting as far as inclusion in the tinyMCEPreInit object, in a property named the same as the selector but the tinyMCE JS seems to do nothing with it.
I also tried adding a readonly argument to the call wp_editor but that has no effect.